# How to push the array values based on which skill belongs to particular question

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array 1.`$allSkills` and 2. `$questionList`.

```
    $allSkills = [
      [ "skillID" => "d45","contentNodes" => [ "leafNodes" => [ "en" => ["1","2","3"] ]]],
      [ "skillID" => "d46","contentNodes" => [ "leafNodes" => [ "en" => ["4","5","6"] ]]],
      [ "skillID" => "d47","contentNodes" => [ "leafNodes" => [ "en" => ["7","8","9"] ]]]
   ];

    $questionList = ["1","3","5","6","8"];
```

Now i want  to find `$questionList` values which skillID belongs to. i have tried but i couldn't get my expected out ,please any one help me out on this.

My Code

```
<?php
$allSkills = [
  [ "skillID" => "d45","contentNodes" => [ "leafNodes" => [ "en" => ["1","2","3"] ]]],
  [ "skillID" => "d46","contentNodes" => [ "leafNodes" => [ "en" => ["4","5","6"] ]]],
  [ "skillID" => "d47","contentNodes" => [ "leafNodes" => [ "en" => ["7","8","9"] ]]]
];

$questionList = ["1","3","5","6","8"];


foreach($allSkills as $skilID => $skilVal){
  $leafNodes = $skilVal['contentNodes']['leafNodes']['en'];
  $result = !empty(array_intersect($leafNodes, $questionList));
  if($result){
    $finalResult[$skilVal['skillID']] = $leafNodes;
  }

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalResult);
?>
```

My Expected output

```
 Array
(
    [d45] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [d46] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
        )

    [d47] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
        )

  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting the intersection into the result, not the entire `$leafNodes` array.

```
foreach($allSkills as $skilID => $skilVal){
    $leafNodes = $skilVal['contentNodes']['leafNodes']['en'];
    $skills = array_intersect($leafNodes, $questionList);
    if($skills){
        $finalResult[$skilVal['skillID']] = $skills;
    }
}
```

Comment: damn you're fast, just missing 1 semicolon after array_intersect()

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result){
$finalResult[$skilVal['skillID']] = array_values(array_intersect($leafNodes, $questionList));}
```